# Adding a Scrollable Directory to a website built in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2010

First off, yes, I do know that Microsoft Word is *not* ideal for building a website. But my client is insisting on it since they want to be able to edit it later on their own and this is the software they have. It's a non-profit with limited resources and can only aford this much thanks to a grant. For the most part, what they want is pretty basic and this doesn't present any major issues I can't find a work-around for...except for one.

They need to have a lengthy directory of members. Ideally, this should be a small scrollable frame (as opposed to just a really long webpage). It should be searchable and have clickable hyperlinks. I had been using Yahoo's SiteBuilder for another client and l found I could create an Excel spreadsheet, save it as an HTML web page, grab the source code, paste it into an iframe and have the result work like what I described. But SiteBuilder is not an option for the current client.

Is there a way of creating the directory in Excel and embedding it into the Word-created webpage and have it scrollable, searchable, and with live hyperlinks?

I can place an Excel document but when it converts to a table it is not scrollable and anything below the boundaries of the table is not visible. It also seems permanently behind a placed piece of artwork used for a backdrop and none of the normal "bring to front" options seem to work. I also found a thread on this site about using a legacy ActiveX textbox, but I don't think that's what I need. Ideally the client should be able to update the directory in Excel.

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas how I can fit this round peg into a square hole?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the answer you're looking for.  But!  Keep reading.

Microsoft Expression Web 4 is (ok, no longer continued but) fantastic!  I use it for my website (http://tiptoptom.co.uk) and it's intuitive and easy to use.  I went from knowing barely anything about websites to that.

It's free software now that it's no longer maintained. I would certainly recommend to your client that they have a look at this.

Word doesn't have this functionality.  You could try using Google Sheets and add an `<iframe>` in, for the embed version of the spreadsheet, but that's about as far as you can go.

The iframe would look something like this:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/ausername/some/more/folders/document.xls"></iframe>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's funny you should mention this because I had come across that program while researching other options! So how would I do an iframe kind of insert along the lines of what I had described in Expression? As I said, I am used to SiteBuilder where I can just drop an iframe box, paste my code, size the area, and I'm good. Thank you!